# Iterate over all Query Values in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm trying to iterate over an unknown number of query values in C#... and can't find anything unrelated to LINQ, which I can't use. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Where are your query values coming from?

Comment: What kind of query are you using? A query for accessing the database using a SqlCommand?

Comment: what kind of a query? SQLServer? DirectoryServices? Filesystem?

Comment: "query values"?  Could you provide a little more information about the collection over which you're trying to iterate?

Comment: Since he has an ASP.Net tag he could also mean querystring.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375372/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-the-querystring-name-value-pairs-into-a-collection/34284894#34284894

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this question is about getting a querystring in ASP.NET, I think the link you are searching for is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx

Essentially, `Request.QueryString` gives you a collection that you can then iterate over.

Comment: It's important to remark that this does not apply to any newer framework than .NET 4.8.1

Answer (score 9):

Using the Request.QueryString gives you a collection that you can iterate over.
Using Request.QueryString.Allkeys allows you to iterate over a collection of strings that represent all of the keys i nthe query string.  Using this we can come up with something like the below code in order to iterate over all keys and get their values.

```
foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
{
    Response.Write("Key: " + key + " Value: " + Request.QueryString[key]);
}
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

If the collection implements IEnumerable you can use a foreach, otherwise use a for loop with the .Length of the collection.