# Is there a way to get all the querystring name/value pairs into a collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, query-string

Is there a way to get all the querystring name/value pairs into a collection?

I'm looking for a built in way in .net, if not I can just split on the & and load a collection.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Yes, use the [`HttpRequest.QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) collection:

> Gets the collection of HTTP query string variables.

You can use it like this:

```
foreach (String key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
{
    Response.Write("Key: " + key + " Value: " + Request.QueryString[key]);
}
```

Comment: Something to point out this will only get you the PAIRS, if you happen to have a querystring such as ?ok you will get nothing from this method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902059/check-if-unassigned-variable-exists-in-request-querystring

Answer (score 10):

Well, `Request.QueryString` already IS a collection. Specifically, it's a `NameValueCollection`. If your code is running in ASP.NET, that's all you need.

So to answer your question: Yes, there is.

Comment: Well, how do you loop over a name value collection and get the name and value out of each element then? While it does implement IEnumerable, looping over it gives you objects.

Answer (score 9):

You can use LINQ to create a List of anonymous objects that you can access within an array:

```
var qsArray = Request.QueryString.AllKeys
    .Select(key => new { Name=key.ToString(), Value=Request.QueryString[key.ToString()]})
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have a querystring ONLY represented as a string, use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx) to parse it into a NameValueCollection.

However, if this is part of a HttpRequest, then use the already parsed QueryString-property of your HttpRequest.

Answer (score 2):

`QueryString` property in `HttpRequest` class is actually [**NameValueCollection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) class. All you need to do is

> NameValueCollection col =
>   Request.QueryString;

Answer (score 1):

Create dictionary of parameters

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters = Request.QueryString.Keys.Cast<string>().ToDictionary(k => k, v => Request.QueryString[v]);
```