# get a array of values from the url in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, request

I am using ASP.NET for the first time.

Here is my issue.
I have a ASP.NET page.
some other website redirects to my webpage and the url is

```
http://localhost/mysite/newpage.aspx?request=424718&to%5B0%5D=111832&to%5B1%5D=1186313&to%5B2%5D=100009#_=_
```

actually what that website send is a request value and an array of id 's

I have to get those values in my page and display them.

I have used @Request["request"] to get the request value. 
But I do not know how to get the id values (since it is an array). I tried @Request["to"] and it gives null.

I also cannot understand that url encoding.. it is supposed to be like this

?request=3435&to=3495&to=435&to=3546

Answer (score 2):

The ids & values that you are looking for, I believe, are in the URL. This is called the querystring.

## Single Values

This code will output each key-value-pair from the querystring. If there are multiple values, they will be comma-delimited.

*C#*

```
foreach (String key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
{
    Response.Write("Key: " + key + " Value: " + Request.QueryString[key]);
}
```

*VB.NET*

```
For Each key as String in Request.QueryString.Allkeys
    Response.Write("Key: " & key & " Value: " & Request.QueryString(key))
Next
```

If you use the above code, you will notice that there is a comma-delimited list of values outputted for the `to` key. This is because the `to` key is used multiple times.

## Multiple Values

This will output each key followed by each key's values.

```
foreach (String key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
{
    var values = Request.QueryString.GetValues(key);

    foreach (String item in values)
    {
      Response.Write("value: " + item + " ";
    }
}
```

This will output each key and then each value for each key, even if there are multiple.

**Reference**

- [Is there a way to get all the querystring name/value pairs into a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375372/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-the-querystring-name-value-pairs-into-a-collection)

Comment: it says Key: to[0] and Key: to[1] etc., I know I can format and check for "to["+%d+"]". But is there a way I can get 'to' as an array

Comment: Ok, I see. I updated the answer to show how to account for multiple values per key. You need the GetValues function

Comment: No.. I mean How do I know what values is the array id. It could be any other array in the query string, right ?

Comment: you can cycle through the ids as follows:

foreach (string key in Request.QueryString.AllKeys) { Response.Write(key); }