# Check if unassigned variable exists in Request.QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

Within the context of an ASP.NET page, I can use Request.QueryString to get a collection of the key/value pairs in the query string portion of the URI.

For example, if I load my page using `http://local/Default.aspx?test=value`, then I can call the following code:

```
//http://local/Default.aspx?test=value

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = Request.QueryString["test"]; // == "value"
}
```

**Ideally what I want to do is check to see if *test* exists at all, so I can call the page using `http://local/Default.aspx?test`** and get a boolean telling me whether test exists in the query string. Something like this:

```
//http://local/Default.aspx?test

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool testExists = Request.QueryString.HasKey("test"); // == True
}
```

So ideally what I want is a boolean value that tell me whether the test variable is present in the string or not.

I suppose I could just use regex to check the string, but I was curious if anybody had a more elegant solution.

I've tried the following:

```
//http://local/Default.aspx?test

Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("test"); // == False  (Should be true)
Request.QueryString.Keys[0];                  // == null   (Should be "test")
Request.QueryString.GetKey(0);                // == null   (Should be "test")
```

This behavior is different than PHP, for example, where I can just use

```php
$testExists = isset($_REQUEST['test']); // == True
```

Comment: Why can't you just check for a `null`?  `If(Request.QueryString["test"] != null)`

Comment: @JonH: Because `Request.QueryString["test"]` returns `null` whether test is present in the query string or not.

Comment: huh?  I'm not sure what you mean, it will only return == null if it doesn't see test in the query string otherwise it returns != null, and if thats the case you can grab the value of test.  I dont see the issue.

Comment: @JonH: I don't want to check the value of test, only to see if it exists. For example, I want `?test` and `test=anyvalue` to both return `true`, but anything else (`?differentkey=anyvalue`) to return `false`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Request.QueryString.GetValues(null)` will get a list of keys with no values

`Request.QueryString.GetValues(null).Contains("test")` will return true

Comment: You just beat me by a few seconds :-) I had to peek into the sourcecode to discover this curious behavior.

Comment: i get a `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.` error with this.

Comment: I also get the error System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Comment: I can only verify that in .Net 4.5 this is still working for me 

? Request.QueryString.GetValues(null).Contains("blah")

false


? Request.QueryString.GetValues(null).Contains("foo")

true

Comment: To avoid ArgumentNullException use this: if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0 && Request.QueryString.GetValues(null).Contains("test"))

Comment: This one ^ will crash when the QueryString is not empty and present. Use this instead: Request.QueryString.ToString().Contains("test"); // ToString will show all QueryStrings even if empty.

Comment: For the code above, be aware that this will work for any query having "test" inside. Ex: "?hello=test. If you want to be more specific use this: Request.QueryString.ToString().Split('&').Any(x => x.Split('=')[0] == "test")

Comment: To remove the NRE you could use `(Request.QueryString.GetValues(null) ?? new string[0]).Contains(key)` I'd wrap this in an extension method similar to @DarkDaskin's answer

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an extension method to solve this task:

```
public static bool ContainsKey(this NameValueCollection collection, string key)
{
    if (collection.AllKeys.Contains(key)) 
        return true;

     // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
    var keysWithoutValues = collection.GetValues(null);
    return keysWithoutValues != null && keysWithoutValues.Contains(key);
}
```

Comment: +1 great answer. As of R#8 you no longer need the disable hint, it appears they updated their analysis of `GetValues(null)`.  One other thing I can point out, don't forget about the overload `Contains(key, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` to avoid case sensitivity.

Answer (score 2):

`Request.QueryString` is a `NameValueCollection`, but items are only added to it if the query string is in the usual `[name=value]*` format. If not, it is empty.

If your `QueryString` was of the form `?test=value`, then `Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("test")` would do what you want. Otherwise, you're stuck doing string operations on `Request.Url.Query`.

Answer (score 2):

I use this.

```
if (Request.Params["test"] != null)
{
    //Is Set
}
else if(Request.QueryString.GetValues(null) != null && 
       Array.IndexOf(Request.QueryString.GetValues(null),"test") > -1)
{
    //Not set
}
else
{
    //Does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY this one, it solved my issue!
It will count either the query string has a value or empty and then you can check the required query string value with the Key.

```
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
           if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["departmentId"] != null)
                {
                    GetSurveyByDeptAndStatus(departmentId: Request.QueryString["departmentId"], status: "Not Surveyed");
                    rbListEmpsSurvey.Items[1].Selected = true;
                }

                else if (Request.QueryString["SurveyStatus"] != null)
                {
                    SatisfactionStatus = Request.QueryString["SurveyStatus"] "";
                    GetSurveyByDeptAndStatus(status: SatisfactionStatus);
                    GetDepartments();
                }}}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Request.QueryString.ToString().Contains("test")
```

This works in the special case where you're looking for a single querystring parameter,  e.g. `MyFile.aspx?test`

For more complex, general, cases then other solutions would be better.

Comment: Hmmm... it could work, but it's not very reliable; it wouldn't pass a decent unit test. The accepted answer is still the best. I wanted to see if the query string contained a variable called `test` (whether or not it contained a value - for example: `?test` or `?test=anyvalue` both return `true`). Checking to see if the string `test` exists *anywhere* in the querystring could produce false positives. For example: `?a=test` - the variable name is `a`, which is not what I'm looking for. Also `?bestest=10` would produce a false positive.

Comment: Good point although for my Use Case it was fine.  I suppose one could throw a regex at the raw querystring.

Comment: Example regex: (?<!=)(\btest\b)(=?|&|$)

Comment: Example test querystring (which the regex matches the three correct cases):  test&aaa=tester&test1=test&mytest=test&test&xxxxx&test=test

Comment: Yea you could use regex to parse HTML too. ;-) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.  "http://local/Default.aspx?test" will be validated using Request.QueryString.ToString.Contains("test")

Comment: Yep, remember I lose reputation too with a downvote. I already indicated that string matching would work in my original question: "I suppose I could just use regex to check the string, but I was curious if anybody had a more elegant solution". This answer is potentially misleading for the reasons I mentioned above. Also, you're missing parentheses after `ToString`. ;-)