# How to check if an 'unknown' parameter is supplied in a Request's Query String?

Tags: c#, request.querystring

For example, if a query string has 2 expected parameters , say. `param1 = "abc"` & `param2 = "def"`.

I know that `Request.QuerySring["abc"]` will check for "abc" in query string.

But is there any way to validate if user enters anything else other than param1 or param2?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you care? if the user enters a value with an identifier that you don't use in your code, then it's meaningless anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375372/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-the-querystring-name-value-pairs-into-a-collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `AllKeys`:

`Request.QueryString.AllKeys`

To get the list of parameters used apart from 'param1' and 'param2':

```
var expectedParams = new [] { "param1", "param2" };
var additionalParams = Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Where(k => !expectedParams.Contains(k));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to retrieve `Request.QuerySring["param1"]` you will get the value **abc**. Now if the user change the KEYS of the query-string you will not able receive it as your are retrieving the query-string values by KEYS. So you dont need to validate users inputs.