# How can I take/catch dynamic parameter(in form of querystring) into .cs file

Tags: asp.net

Hello I came up with situation where I am taking value from user in the form 
of querystring.

```
 Ex: sitename/sample.aspx?username=''&userid=''
```

cs file

```
string Username = "";
if (Request.QueryString["username"] != null)      
{
    Username = Request.QueryString["username"].ToString();
}
string userid = "";
if (Request.QueryString["userid"] != null)      
{
   userid = Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString();
}
```

Name of first 2 parameter is fix,so name name of querystring is fix.After these 2 parameter,user may enter or may not enter any parameter.Parameter count can be from 1 to many and  vary in datatype.

```
 Ex: sitename/sample.aspx?username=''&userid=''&Date=
 Ex: sitename/sample.aspx?username=''&userid=''&Date=&amount=
```

how can I take/catch dynamic parameter into .cs file?

Comment: You can iterate through all the query string values like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2375380/70713

Comment: Thanks Dan Dumitru,it helped me.